# UI5 application (in WebIDE): sap.m.ColumnListItem: Change entire row color depending on a value in one column: What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I googled how to change the color of a row inside a table ( ColumnListItem ) based on  a value inside a column. I found a lot of google results and from all of the results I chose the one, which avoids to use predefined ( or individually defined ) css's inside my project folder.
BTW, even inside the F12-browser-tools (modifying the css orsuch stuff at the frontend) seems not to work as expected.

I followed this approach ( quite old post ) and cannot get it working:

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3360580

The table line simply should become green, yellow, or red.

This is my code so far, inside onInit ( first part, creating the template )

```
var oTable = this.byId("companySecret"); 
        var oView = this.getView();

        var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{Col1}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{Col2}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{Col3}"
                }),
                //
                // ALL OTHER COLUMNS
                // 
                // The only difference is that I do this inside the "loop".

                new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text: "{Color}"
                }).bindProperty("text", "Color",function(cellValue)
                    {
                        var backgroundColor = "red";         

                        var cellId = this.getId();

                        var row_col = $("#"+cellId);

                        // As You see, I am quite desperate
                        $("#"+cellId).css("background-color","#FF0000");
                        $("#"+cellId).parent().css("background-color","#FF0000");
                        $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().css("background-color",'#FF0000');
                        $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().parent().css("background-color","#FF0000");
                        $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().parent().parent().css("background-color","#FF0000");
                        $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("background-color","#FF0000");


                        return cellValue;
                    })

            ]
        });
```

Immediately after these lines, the binding is initiated like this:

```
        var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_COMPANY_SECRET/";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sUrl, false);
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindAggregation("items", {path: "/Company_Secret", template: oTemplate });
```

So, what am I missing ? In the referred link the adopted answer is flagged as "helpful" so it MUST work. Any hints ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate a table line, I generally use a custom attribute on the row via XML:

```
<Table>
  <columns>
    <Column><Text text="value"/></Column>
  </columns>
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem type="Active">
      <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="color" value="{= ${MyArgument} ? 'red' : 'green'}" writeToDom="true" />
      </customData>          
      <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier text="{Value}"/>
      </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
</Table>
```

This writes a data attribute called `data-color` to the `tr` element on the DOM with value either `red` or `green`. Expand this with your own logic, or use a formatter like you would on any other value if the check is to long or unwieldy.

You can then manipulate the attribute via your included CSS file:

```
tr[data-color="red"] {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Works for me.

You might be able to do something like

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-color="red"]').forEach(s => s.style.backgroundColor = 'red');
```

Comment: Why? When creating a new project from WebIDE, SAP creates one for you. You can however target the tag via `document.querySelector` I imagine.

Comment: I want to know, WHY my code, which is flagged as "helpful answer" insise sdn does not run properly... maybe inside onInit is to early, someone said, the dom is not accessible there...

Comment: that's possible, the dom is not ready until after the view renders, but then, you'd expect the code to kind of not go there at all? You could try to move your code into one of the screen rendering events and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah, did that just right now... still no effect. In my chrome I enabled the SAPUI5 plugin and can inspect all the elements. and what I see is, that NO element(and parents) receive the background property... can it be, that sapui5 internally forbids to set those html-properties, which they do not offer ???

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already an old question, but might be able to help others.

[Jorg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456933/7559319) is probably the cleaner approach. I use the same approach as well.

Generally, it's cleaner and a lot safer to avoid using and accessing auto-generated Control-IDs (especially with the jQuery selector) as these IDs are most likely to change whenever the model it's bound to is refreshed.

By using the CustomData-CSS approach, you get to take advantage of the binding and not worrying about changing IDs or finding the right ID for a list/row item that's bound to change anyway, when the model is refreshed.

You just have to maintain some CSS. Which is simpler and much cleaner. :)

If it helps, I converted your code to conform to Jorg's answer.
See below:

```
new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: "{Color}"
}).addCustomData(new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
    key: "color",
    value: "{= $(argument) ? 'red' : 'green'}",
    writeToDom: true
}));
```

And in CSS, should be the same as Jorg's:

```
tr[data-color="red"] {
   background-color: red;
}
```

I hope this helps!